# C++/WinRT: CoreApplication::Run(IFrameworkViewSource const&) is throwing E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm trying to figure out why at this point in the code I'm getting an E_INVALIDARG hresult:

```
// main.cpp
class App : public implements<App, IFrameworkView>
{
    // stuff ...
};


class AppFactory : public implements<AppFactory, IFrameworkViewSource>
{
public:
    IFrameworkView CreateView()
    {
        return make<App>();
    }
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE, 
    _In_ HINSTANCE, 
    _In_ LPWSTR,
    _In_ int)
{
    init_apartment();
    auto vpf = make<AppFactory>();
    CoreApplication::Run(vpf);     // <-- throwing E_INVALIDARG somewhere inside CoreApplication::Run
    uninit_apartment();

    return S_OK;
}
```

I'd have expected a compile error if I didn't do something required by a class inheriting implements<AppFractory, IFrameworkViewSource>, but as far as I know I'm checking (static) boxes.

fwiw the exception is triggered here:

```
// Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.h
template <typename D> auto consume_Windows_ApplicationModel_Core_ICoreApplication<D>::Run(winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::IFrameworkViewSource const& viewSource) const
{
    check_hresult(WINRT_IMPL_SHIM(winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::ICoreApplication)->Run(*(void**)(&viewSource)));
}
```

The thing inside check_result(...) is what's returning E_INVALIDARG, and subsequently triggering the exception. I'm not a super expert at writing windows applications, largely still in the "copy the template and hope it works while trying to understand something" phase. If there's some kind of tool I should be using to understand what the actual argument I'm passing is that is invalid, I'd appreciate some kind of pointer. I would think if I'm not passing the correct thing here, the strong type check of the argument would trigger a compile error and I'd have an opportunity to address the issue.

Honestly I'm lost here, would appreciate a hint towards where to look to resolve my issue. Thank you.

Update:

Don't know if this is relevant but in the Output tab in VS a line prints out:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA6D9A4FD9 (KernelBase.dll) in MyProgram.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80070057 : 'serverName'.
```

I have no idea what this is... "serverName"? I don't even see a mention of this in the CoreApplication::Run docs.

Comment: Do you get the same `hresult_error` when executing `CoreApplication::Run(AppFactory());` instead? Also, does `AppFactory` implement the `IFrameworkViewSource` interface?

Comment: Doesn't AppFactory already implement IFrameworkViewSource that via `implement<AppFactory, IFrameworkViewSource>`?

Comment: You're going to have to provide an implementation for its [`CreateView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.iframeworkviewsource.createview) member, that returns a valid `IFrameworkView` interface implementation. This [MSDN Magazine article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/january/c-introducing-c-winrt) shows how to do that.

Comment: I actually have that implemented. I just left it out because the program isn't even reaching the point where it goes into the `CreateView` method. fwiw it won't even let me compile if I don't implement this method.

Comment: CoreApplication is for UWP apps. Is your app a UWP app?

Comment: This might be it. The project was started as an empty project and I brought in the WinRT nuget package thinking that was what I needed. I guess there's extra stuff that's not related to C++ code that I need for CoreApplication to work?

Comment: If you're not a UWP app, then don't use CoreApplication::Run. Your app is already running. Just start doing stuff.

Comment: @ray I was looking through your articles but couldn't find one that would contrast the different application models (Classic Desktop, UWP, WinUI(?)), together with their respective framework representations. Did I just not look close enough, or is that blog entry actually missing? Sounds like a topic that could easily [nerd-snipe](https://xkcd.com/356/) a 10x HTML `<table>` ninja guru.

Comment: There are two application models: Classic and UWP. (WinUI is a library that can be used in both Classic and UWP apps. It is not an application model) Each application model has a choice of frameworks (including "no framework").